# How do I get the table names referenced by a trigger in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, dependencies

I have a trigger with me and I want that which tables are being referenced by this trigger.Also same for Rules in sql server.I have a Rule in my db and I want the table name on which it is created.
Also same for Indexes.

=========================EDIT===================

In case of following trigger Definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON dbo.[Employee_Test] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @empid int;
    declare @empname varchar(100);
    declare @empsal decimal(10,2);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i; 
    select @empname=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
    select @empsal=i.Emp_Sal from inserted i;   
    set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

    insert into Employee_Test_Audit
           (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    values(@empid,@empname,@empsal,@audit_action,getdate());

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

In this case 2 tables should be shown as dependent table which are `Employee_Test` and `Employee_Test_Audit`.How can I get these names?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) AS tablename, *
FROM [databasename].sys.triggers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code : 
"sp_depends trigger name"
This will provide all details like stored procedure called and user tables referenced by the trigger.